# Creating a script for ASP.NET membership table structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3, appharbor

I'm creating an AppHarbor MVC3 application and want to use the standard membership provider support. The AppHarbor guys told me I needed to create script for the table structure that I can run on my AppHarbor database. I'm not really familiar with databases, however. How do I go about creating and executing a script for the default membership tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the command line aspnet_regsql.exe. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx. Excerpt:

Step 2. Install the Membership Database

Before you can use the SqlMembershipProvider, you must install the SQL Server membership database.

To install the membership database, log on to your server with an account that has authority to administrate SQL Server (such as the Administrator account). Open the Visual Studio 2005 command prompt, and run the following command:

> aspnet_regsql.exe -E -S localhost -A m
>
> Where:
>
> -E indicates authenticate using the Windows credentials of the currently
>   logged on user.
>   -S (server) indicates the name of the server where the database will be
>   installed or is already installed.
>   -A m indicates add membership support. This creates the tables and stored
>   procedures required by the membership
>   provider. Note   The Aspnet_regsql
>   tool is also used to install database
>   elements for other ASP.NET 2.0
>   features, such as Role Management,
>   Profile, Web Parts Personalization,
>   and Web Events. Other command-line
>   arguments perform database operations
>   for these other features. You can use
>   Aspnet_regsql without any command line
>   arguments by using a wizard that
>   allows you to specify connection
>   information for your SQL Server and
>   install or remove the database
>   elements for all of the supported
>   features.

Comment: I don't think I can log on to the database server on AppHarbor.

Comment: You don't have to connect to a database to use the aspnet_regsql command line tool. You simply use it to create a text file that will contain all of the create object scripts

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx. See the -sqlexportonly command line argument

Comment: I'm confused... the excerpt says "log on to your server with an account that has authority to administrate SQL Server (such as the Administrator account)." I have a db url, username, pw, and connection string. I know 0 about DBA, should I be able to log on with that info?

Comment: Okay! I didn't see your 2nd comment before posting. Looks like it worked! I will experiment a little bit and accept your answer if everything checks out. Thanks Shan!

Comment: Also, you *can* connect remotely to your database at AppHarbor (I know, because I have a database there, and I've done it).  Use SQL Management studio or something like it to connect and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great article here:
http://www.nashcoding.com/2011/02/05/using-the-forms-authentication-membership-provider-on-appharbor/comment-page-1/#comment-477

1.Start a Visual Studio command prompt by going to Start -> All Programs -> Visual Studio 2010 -> Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Studio Command Prompt.

2.Run the following command, using the your AppHarbor database settings to fill in the values in brackets: aspnet_regsql.exe -S [Host] -d [Name] -U [Username] -P [Password] -A all

3.In your MVC project, open your Web.config file.

4.Replace the connectionString for ApplicationServices with the connection string found on your AppHarbor database page.

Comment: The problem I have with this approach is that the application will then always use the AppHarbor database, even when running locally.  Is there a way around that?